# Using istream_iterator and string to read textfile

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

I want to read textfile to string variable, but after execute below instructions string is empty:

```
fstream shaderFile(fileName.c_str(),ios::in);
string shaderSrc = string(istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile),istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this snippet?

Comment: Maybe, the file doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've seen that filename was bad. 30 seconds for debugger, but first I thought it was problem with constructor or something similar. My question was somewhat stupid. Thanks anyway.